# convert base64 string to image with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, image, titanium, encode

Am developing an application with Titanium. I need to convert base64 string which i would be getting from JSON to an image.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML

Answer (score 26):

You can just create an `img` element and change its `src` with the required data:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS..." />
```

Comment: Provided the image is small enough, yeah, and if you don't need to support IE7 and lower: http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri Browser limits on the length of `data:` URI strings vary wildly. I think IE8's is the lowest at 32k.

Comment: I am developing with Titanium, there is no img tag as everything is javascript. I know for images that are on the file system i need to do something like this: rightImage: Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + 'images/ui/backimage.png'. But I dont know what to do for images on a remote location

Comment: Can you please add further details on what you exactly want (editing your question).

Answer (score 3):

For Titanium, you use the built in conversion utility [`Titanium.Utils.base64decode`:](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Utils-method-base64decode)

```
var imageFromBase64 = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    image : Titanium.Utils.base64decode("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS..."),
});
```

This converts a base64 string to a blob, which can be used in an ImageView.