# How to get the image datatype in webmethod c# and display in image tag html

Tags: c#, html, image, web-services, binary

```
create table image_tbl(imgname varchar(100), my_image image)
```

I have table which contains many data `username`,etc and `my_image` whose datatype is `IMAGE` And i am able to save the binary data of image in database. Now i want to retrieve the image and display in the image tag.

I am using the webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
     public bytes[] get_image(string  prefix)
     {
         SqlDataReader dr;
         string user_id = prefix;
bytes[] image; 
         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cn.ConnectionString))
         {
             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
             {
                 cmd.CommandText = "select * from image_tbl WHERE (id = @user_id)";
                 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", user_id);
                 cmd.Connection = con;
                 con.Open();
                 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                 if (dr.HasRows)
                 {
                     while (dr.Read())
                     {
                        image=dr["my_image"].ToString(); 
                     }

                 } dr.Close();
                 con.Close();
             }
         }
         return result;
     }
     }
```

What will the way to read the byte image and then display it in html ??

Comment: how is this webservice consumed? JS, SOAP? Is this really a webservice or a Page Method?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941980/problems-converting-image-to-bytes-and-then-to-string/27942079#27942079 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429234/convert-base64-string-to-image-with-javascript

Comment: this method is called via ajax method..