# How to make a base64 image url to a real image with javascript or jquery?

Tags: image, base64

I'd exchanged a div tag to a base64 image url with html2canvas plugin. And I need to make this base64 url to a real image so I can add this image to an editor without download. What should I do ?

Comment: Do you have to actually **_create_** the image file? If you only need to show the image, you can add the base64-string as the source for the `img` tag, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9429284/717088

Comment: Yes, I have show the image at my page, but I can't add it to my rich text field, so I need some solution to deal with this.